# Jquery - onclick event - factorization

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I use video.js seek option with functions to set time to seek:

```
$('#0s').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    player.currentTime(0);
});

$('#10s').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    player.currentTime(10);
});

$('#20s').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    player.currentTime(20);
  });
});
```

With these links:

```
<a href="#" id="0s">0s</a>
<a href="#" id="10s">10s</a>
<a href="#" id="20s">20s</a>
```

How to use just one function ?
My try:

```
$(".link1").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var time = $('this').attr('time');
    player.currentTime(time);

});
```

With this link:

```
<a href="#" id="0s" class="link1" time="0">0s</a>
<a href="#" id="10s" class="link1" time="10">10s</a>
<a href="#" id="20s" class="link1" time="20">20s</a>
```

They provide this url to test code:
http://jsbin.com/ukIDoSa/4/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the quotes around `this`

```
var time = $('this').attr('time');
```

should be

```
var time = $(this).attr('time');

player.currentTime(parseInt(time, 10)); // make sure you pass an integer.
```

Comment: Is it required to use parseInt on time or not ?

Comment: @Toki8. That would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Use var time = $(this).attr('time'); not "this" right way is only this